# calculating date fields in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

myst="""Uptime: 905034  Threads: 5  Questions: 1215  Slow queries: 3  Opens: 190  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 4  Queries per second avg: 0.001
Uptime: 905094  Threads: 5  Questions: 1216  Slow queries: 3  Opens: 190  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 4  Queries per second avg: 0.001
Uptime: 905154  Threads: 5  Questions: 1217  Slow queries: 3  Opens: 190  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 4  Queries per second avg: 0.001
"""
u_cols=[]
for i in range(29):
    u_cols.append('column'+str(i))

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=' ', names = u_cols)
```

What I have tried:

```
df['IST_DATE']=df['column1'].apply((lambda x: dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(seconds=60)))

In [127]: df[['column1','IST_DATE']]

Out[127]:
    column1     IST_DATE
0   905034  2015-03-06 15:55:55.993769
1   905094  2015-03-06 15:55:55.993791
2   905154  2015-03-06 15:55:55.993803
```

The expected result should have a difference of 1 minute per row. For e.g.

```
Out[127]:
    column1     IST_DATE
0   905034  2015-03-06 15:53:55.993769
1   905094  2015-03-06 15:54:55.993791
2   905154  2015-03-06 15:55:55.993803
```

The uptime is calculated every minute. The last row in the dataframe shows the seconds elapsed as of now. So for e.g. 905154 means that the server was started on Feb 24

```
>>> dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(seconds=905154)
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 24, 4, 40, 16, 28786)
```

In other words, the 'column1' that represents seconds from start-time (Feb 24 in this case) should be converted to readable dates.

---

update:

How do I find the last value of column1?
I need to use that value (for e.g. 905154) like this ....

```
df['IST_DATE']=df['column1'].apply((lambda x: dt.datetime.today() - pd.Timedelta(905154,unit='s') + pd.Timedelta(x,unit='s')))

df[['column1','IST_DATE']]
```

---

update 1

I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
myval=df.tail(1)['column1']

df['IST_DATE']=df['column1'].apply((lambda x: dt.datetime.today() - pd.Timedelta(str(myval),unit='s') + pd.Timedelta(x,unit='s')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Head and tail are not the correct way to index pandas data.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

u_cols=[]
for i in range(29):
    u_cols.append('column'+str(i))

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/root/status_success.txt', sep=' ', names = u_cols)

myval=df['column1'].iloc[-1]
df['IST_DATE']=df['column1'].apply((lambda x: dt.datetime.today() - pd.Timedelta(myval,unit='s') + pd.Timedelta(x,unit='s')))
```